# Apache Tomcat no puede iniciar

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Cuando inicio mi tomcat desde Elclipse STS
se despliega este error!

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
Publishing failed Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Could not publish server configuration: 
    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\WEBSERVICES BRASIL\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml
    (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada).
    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\WEBSERVICES BRASIL\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml
    (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
```

Comment: Tu servidor presento este problemas apenas o es la primera ves que lo configuras?

Comment: Ya estaba trabajando con él anteriormente solo que de la nada me apareció éso!
Esto quiere decir que apenas presentó el problema.
Que tengo que hacer?

Comment: Primero verifica si la ruta `C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\WEBSE.....` existe y si existe si contiene el archivo `server.xml`

Comment: efectivamente no existe la parte de conf\server.xml De donde obtengo uno?

Comment: Una de las cosas que para mi ha sido mas efectivo ha sido eliminar el server desde eclipse (STS) y volverlo a agregar `Window -> Show View -> Servers` No se si tengas alguna configuaración adicional que haga complicado este proceso, pero sino, deberia bastar, asi eclipse vuelve a crear todos los archivos que necesita para el arranque

Comment: Tengo un tomcat en la ubicacion C:\\apache-tomcat-v.8
y cuando creo el server desde Window ->Show View ->Servers y señalo la ruta de mi tomcat donde lo guardo en este caso en C:\\  al agregarlo al eclipse me sale ahora otro error!

Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Cuando inicio el servidor me sale el mensaje anterior, ahora es otro nuevo problema!