# Eclipse STS aparece error del servidor

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Cuando inicio mi **Eclipse STS** me aparece un error como el siguiente:

[image: Initializing tooling]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con respecto a este error de eclipse?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Apache Tomcat no puede iniciar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38229/apache-tomcat-no-puede-iniciar)

Comment: Puedes agregar por favor el Exception Stack Trace, que te manda en la consola.